# mapping JSON to an Object

Tags: javascript, json, object, mapping

I have a JSON file that was converted from a csv and is too big to hand edit.  Its' syntax is one large array I think.  The data is from a group of routers and I aim to build router objects.  The way the current CSV to JSON file is organized by each row and I want to pick out each router and have an object with router name, the all bandwidth measurements associated with that router.

How would you approach this?  I'm attempting to take care of all of this when I iterate through the JSON file and when the router changes, I start a new instance of the router object.  I'm a no longer a newb, just a slow learner.  So would the next step be to create a router class with js and populate the class with what I pull out of my giant JSON array, or could/should I do with out the handwritten class and create all the objects on the fly? (can I create objects on the fly.

Current JSON (it goes on for pages, each router having a few hundred entries in the csv:

```
[
   {
        "Router": "RouterID1",
        "TimeStamp": "2012/01/01 06:00:00",
        "transferBytes": "23235",
        "ReceivedBytes":  "29903"
   },
   {
        "Router": "RouterID1",
        "TimeStamp": "2012/01/01 06:05:00",
        "transferBytes": "21235",
        "ReceivedBytes":  "22103"
   }
   {
        "Router": "RouterID2",
        "TimeStamp": "2012/01/01 06:00:00",
        "transferBytes": "23235",
        "ReceivedBytes":  "29903"
   },
   {
        "Router": "RouterID2",
        "TimeStamp": "2012/01/01 06:05:00",
        "transferBytes": "21235",
        "ReceivedBytes":  "22103"
   }
]
```

@amnotiam: the router types are gauranteed to be adjecent to each other

This might not be valid but here is the structure I think I'm going for:

```
[
   {
        "Router": "RouterID1"
        "TimeStamp": array of timestamps
        "transferBytes": array of bytes transferred for each timestamp
        "ReceivedBytes":  array of bytes received for each timestamp
   },
   {
        "Router": "RouterID2",
         "TimeStamp": array of timestamps
        "transferBytes": array of bytes transferred for each timestamp
        "ReceivedBytes":  array of bytes received for each timestamp
   }
]
```

@Bergi I want to make an object for each router with there historical data contained with in the object.  Right know I have an object for every time entry. (I think)

@Rick Good call, I will be and will probably ask that question later:)

Comment: Are the routers organized so that the same router types are guaranteed to be adjacent to each other? And can you give an illustration of what the resulting data structure should look like?

Comment: You already have a lot of objects for routers in your (parsed json) array. To what do you want to transform them?

Comment: Are you going to be parsing/making objects every time the page loads or refreshes? Creating all these and caching these would probably be better so you don't have to parse the data x number of times when the router is changed.

Comment: Responses in the bottom of the question

Comment: Are you trying to do this all in a browser via javascript? or do you have some other language you are going to parse it with?

Comment: @BryanAgee  All in the browser I think.

Comment: I updated my answer to show the same idea with no php--sorry about that =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can really just create the objects on the fly.  It's not going to be any faster to hardcode a set of router objects, and it's likely you'll make mistakes by handwriting.

Take a look at this : http://jsfiddle.net/aSbm6/

Comment: Exactly what I want to do.  I just i'm unsure how to have my structure my object on the fly with a JSON structure I don't want.

Comment: @rd42 do you want a quick lookup by router name?  For example, you would lookup a specific timestamp like so `routers["DWG-350"].usage[1].timestamp`

Comment: exaclty.  I want to view historical data from a spreadsheet generated by each router.

Comment: I do believe that's it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would start with turning the json into a php variable, so that you can operate on it more easily. It looks like your Json is one big array of objects, so it would look like this:

```
$routerArray = json_decode($yourJsonString);
```

Then you can iterate and get your data:

```
$newRouterObjectsArray = array();

foreach($routerArray as $routerObject) {
    if (empty($newRouterObjectsArray[$Router])) {
        // instantiate new router here:
        $newRouterObjectsArray[$Router] = new Router([params]);
    }
    // any other logic, assuming that the router does exist
}
```

If you're doing this directly in javascript, it would look like:

```
var routerArray = JSON.parse([yourJsonString]);
var newRouterObjects = {};

for (routerEntry in routerArray) {
    if ('undefined' == typeof newRouterObjects[routerEntry->Router]) {
        //if this router doesn't exist yet, create it
        newRouterObjects[routerEntry->Router] = new Router([params]);
    }
    // update totals, etc.
}
```

Comment: I don't think that this project is in php?

Comment: That's ok, it can still help.

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.parse`--or your library's equivalent--if given your JSON file, will return an array of objects, so you don't need to create objects.

If we call `data` the JSON string in your example then:

```
var routers = JSON.parse(data);
routers[0].Router === "DWG-350"; // true
routers[1].TimeStamp === "2012/01/01 06:05:00"; // true

routers[0].Router === routers[1].Router; // true
routers[0].TimeStamp === routers[1].TimeStamp; // false
```

If you need to do logic or filtering then you can use all the objects in `routers` as Javascript objects, because they are.

It's unclear exactly what you're trying to do, though.

I think this is the logic that you want:

```
var routers = JSON.parse(data), // or jQuery.parseJSON()
    aggregate = {};


for (var i = 0, max = routers.length;
     i < max;
     i++) {

     var router = routers[i];
     if (typeof aggregate[routers[i].Router] === 'undefined') {
         aggregate[router['Router']] = {"TimeStamp": [],
                                         "ReceivedBytes": []}
                                         "TransferredBytes": []};

     }

     aggregate[router['Router']]["TimeStamp"]
         .push(router['TimeStamp']);
     aggregate[router['Router']]["ReceivedBytes"]
         .push(router['ReceivedBytes']);
     aggregate[router['Router']]["TransferredBytes"]
         .push(router['TransferredBytes']);
 }
```

Comment: @quodliberator  I'm unclear how to ask it too :)  I think to sum it up.  I want to resturcture my objects from the JSON structure i'm reading in.  Your answer looks promising.

Comment: what kind of structure do you want them to have? Put another way: what properties of the routers do you care about?